# How to disable http cache for electron app after packaging to .exe using electron-packager

Tags: electron, electron-packager

I have an electron app, that loads some css's from spring boot server.
When I run app from npm from sources, I can run as

```
ng build && electron . --disable-http-cache
```

and it works without the cache.
If I build my app with electron-packager to app.exe, how can I disable cache.
Start .exe-file with --disable-http-cache doesn't work

**UPDATE**
The only approach that works is to clear cache from main process before app loads the page. But is there any another way to disable cache?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Another possibility is to use Electron's [`commandLine.appendSwitch ()`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appcommandlineappendswitchswitch-value) in the main process on the `app` object, right before anything gets executed:

```js
const { app } = require ("electron");

app.commandLine.appendSwitch ("disable-http-cache");
// any other main process code
```

This will append `--disable-http-cache` to Chromium's command line, just like appending it to the `electron` command would. When having this in code, you do no longer have to run your app with appending this switch as it will automatically be added.

Answer (score 2):

You can also add a [`no-cache`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#no-cache_2) header inside `loadURL()` of the route that is requesting the css (*or even the root route*)

```js
webContents.loadURL(url, {"extraHeaders" : "pragma: no-cache\n"})
```

A complete mini [example gist](https://gist.github.com/shalkam/c1575814a62c0e6d22d8139dd1c7d414#file-no-cache-electron-js-L16)